# com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreException: cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

i m trying to insert few 100,000 entities in a batch and getting following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreException: cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call
at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:114)
at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:80)
at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:85)
at com.tribalfusion.openbidder.datastorecommons.DatastoreHelper.commitRequest(DatastoreHelper.java:117)
at com.tribalfusion.openbidder.datastorecommons.DatastoreHelper.upsert(DatastoreHelper.java:97)
at com.tribalfusion.openbidder.datastorecommons.test.DatastoreTester.main(DatastoreTester.java:36)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1047)
at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:77)
... 4 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53787', transport: 'socket'
```

I checked datastore documentation and nowhere limit of 500 entities per write op is mentioned. is there anyway to store any number of entities in a batch op.

Answer (score 1):

Using many small batches or few large batches does not affect the number of write ops it takes to write a set of data. However, ensuring that entities with the same root key are in the same batch will affect the maximum write rate.

The GAE thick clients automatically split requests and merge results so that all requests have less than 500 entities. The HTTP API may eventually be updated to do this as well, but doesn't today.

Comment: Has GAE updated this at all? I seemed to still be getting the 500 batch limit.

Comment: I am getting the error also. I got it on 21 April 2018

Comment: Just got it on 13.08.2020 with put_multi

Answer (score 1):

The google documentation do talk about the limits. **Maximum number of entities that can be passed to a Commit operation in the Cloud Datastore API should not be more than 500.**

[Complete article here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits)

There are 3 possible solutions for this problem:

1. Increase your quota/limits by contacting GCP support
2. Commit in batches of 500
3. Limit the number of records to 500

[Check this blog for details](http://teknocean.com/index.php/2019/06/01/cannot-write-more-than-500-entities-in-a-single-call/)